# Can one autoscroll NiceScroll JQuery Plugin?

Tags: jquery

I have the [nicescroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/) plugin working perfect, but what I need it to do is scroll to the BOTTOM of the latest update automatically. I don't need a `resize()` lesson, that works fine. It appears the plugin has no methods.

Is there is a like plugin that does??

Answer (score 5):

You don't need any further plugins, you have to use normal jquery function instead:

```
$("#yourdiv").scrollTop($("#yourdiv").prop("scrollHeight"));
```

Answer (score 2):

$(element).getNiceScroll().doScrollPos(0,$(last-element).position().top);

Answer (score 1):

I met the same kind of problem. But what I need to do is detect when scrollbar touches the bottom.
I found the solution on github:

```
var nice = $("#yourDiv").getNiceScroll();
if(nice.getScrollTop() == nice.page.maxh) {
    // the scrollbar touches the bottom now
}
```

See also: https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/issues/71

Hope it helps.

PS: My nicescroll version is 3